# I don't understand what does" double *array[50]" mean?

Tags: c++

does it mean that there is an array of 50, and each one of the 50 is a pointer to double? if so then does that mean that array[i] will contain addresses only that point to another place in the heap ?

Answer (score 2):

> does [`double *array[50]`] mean that there is an array of 50

Yes.

> and each one of the 50 is a pointer to double?

Yes.

> if so then does that mean that array[i] will contain addresses only that point to another place in the heap ?

No. There's no such meaning. Each of the pointers can point to any object in any part of the memory, not only "heap". In fact, the C++ language is agnostic to the concept of heap.

---

Note that context of a declaration can change its meaning. If this was a declaration of a function argument, then the answer would be different.

Answer (score 1):

It means an array that contains 50 `double *`, that is pointers to doubles. In the initialization `double *array[50]` you are not assigning the pointers to anything, so they point to nothing. Just like if you do this:

```
double *p; // P doesn't point to anything, using it will cause you issues.
double a; // a is a automatic storage duration instantiation of a double.
p = &a; // now p points to a.
```

So for each of the pointers in your array, you need to assign them to some memory before they can be used.